# How can I play an audio clip in a (MIDI) sequence in Java?

Tags: java, audio, midi, javasound

I am attempting to write a very simple DAW in Java but am having trouble playing an audio clip in a sequence. I have looked into both the sampled and MIDI classes in Java Sound but what I really need is a hybrid of the two.

It seems that with the MIDI classes you cannot use a sequencer for example, to play your own audio clip. 
I have attempted to write my own sequencer using scheduling to play a javax.sound.sampled.Clip in a sequence but the timings vary far too much. It is not really a viable option as it doesn't keep time.

Does anybody have any suggestions of how I could get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can attest that an audio mixing system combining aspects of MIDI and samples can be written in Java, as I wrote my own and it currently works with samples and a couple real-time synths that I also wrote.

The key is making the audio data of the samples available on a per-frame basis and a frame-counting command-processor/audio-mixer that both manages the execution of "commands," and collects and mixes the audio frame data. With 44100 fps, that's accuracy in the vicinity of 0.02 milliseconds. I can describe in more detail if requested.

Another way to go, probably saner, though I haven't done it personally, would be to make use of a [Java bridge](https://github.com/jaudiolibs/jnajack) to a system such as [Jack](https://jackaudio.org/applications/).

---

EDIT: Answering questions in comment (12/8/19).

Audio sample data in Java is usually either held in memory (Java uses `Clip`) or read from a .wav file. Because the individual frames are not exposed by `Clip`, I wrote an alternate, and use it to hold the data as signed floats ranging -1 to 1. Signed floats are a common way to hold audio data that we are going to perform multiple operations upon.

For playback of .wav audio, Java combines reading the data with `AudioInputStream` and outputting with `SourceDataLine`. Your system will have to sit in the middle, intercepting the `AudioInputStream`, convert to PCM float frames, and counting the frames as you go.

A number of sources or tracks can be processed at the same time, and merged (simple addition of the normalized floats) to a single signal. This signal can be converted back to bytes and sent out for playback via a single `SourceDataLine`.

Counting output frames from an arbitrary 0th frame from the single `SourceDataLine` will help with keeping constituent incoming tracks coordinated, and will provide the frame number reference used to schedule any additional commands that you wish to execute prior to that frame being output (e.g., changing a volume/pan of a source, or a setting on a synth).

My personal alternate to a Clip is very similar to [AudioCue](https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue) which you are welcome to inspect and use. The main difference is that for better or worse, I'm processing everything one frame at a time in my system, and `AudioCue` and its "Mixer" process buffer loads. I've had several very credible people criticize my personal per-frame system as inefficient, so when I made the public API for `AudioCue`, I bowed to that preconception. [There are ways to add buffering to a per-frame system to recapture that efficiency, and per-frame makes scheduling simpler. So I'm sticking with my per-frame logical scheme.]

Comment: Thanks for your comment Phil. 
I understand the concept of splitting the samples into frames and assembling into a new stream based on "commands" that are received and am interested in exploring that. 
How did you split the wav files up? Did you read them into a byte array and do it that way?
Also, how did you then try to play the new 'stream'? I presume it wasn't by writing out a whole new .wav file.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use a sequencer to play your own clips directly.
In the MIDI world, you have to deal with samples, instruments, and soundbanks.

Very quickly, a sample is the audio data + informations such as looping points, note range covered by the sample, base volume and envelopes, etc.
An instrument is a set of samples, and a soundbank contain a set of instruments.
If you want to use your own sounds to play some music, you must make a soundbank out of them.

You will also need to use another implementation than the default provided by Java, because that default only read soundbanks in a proprietary format, which is gone since at least 15 and perhaps even 20 years.
Back in 2008-2009, there existed for example Gervill. It was able to read SF2 and DLS soundbanks. SF2 and DLS are two popular soundbank formats, several programs exist in the market, free or paid, to edit them.

If you want to go from the other way round, starting with sampled, that's also exact as you ahve noticed, you can't rely on timers, task schedule, Thread.sleep and the like to have enough precision.
The best precision you can achieve by using those is around 10ms, what's of course far too few to be acceptable for music.

The usual way to go here is to generate the audio of your music by mixing your audio clips yourself into the final clip. So you can achieve frame precision.
In fact that's very roughly what does a MIDI synthesizer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know if Gervill is the best thing to use nowadays?

Comment: I don't know at all. I even don't know if Gervill still exist and work with the latest versions of Java after Java 8.